# Crunch, lint.xml  - откуда взялось и что это означает?

Tags: android

Недавно заметил - в проекте в директории bin\res появилась папка crunch в которой появились вложенные папки drawable-hdpi,mdpi,xhdpi,xxhdpi. И теперь в них сохраняются все графические ресурсы вместо обычного пути bin\res\drawable-hdpi,mdpi,xhdpi,xxhdpi.

В проекте чуть пониже манифеста появился файл lint.xml со следующим содержанием:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<lint>
<issue id="CutPasteId" severity="ignore" />
</lint>
```

И что всё это может означать и какие последствия будет иметь для проекта?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

crunch - это новое в android утилитах.  Если я правильно понял, то это что то вроде кеша. А вот [lint](http://tools.android.com/tips/lint) - это достаточно старая утилита для проверки кода. Она может делать проверку на корректность использование функций. К примеру, пишете, в Android.manifest, что программа пишется для sdk 15, а начинаете использовать функции с 17. Правильно настроенный lint поможет это выявить.

Comment: Т.е. это системные проверки и дальше проблем не предвидится?

Comment: lint вполне себе может быть проверкой для Вас (собственно это и есть его назначение). Я думаю, там запускается какой то минимальный набор проверок. А с `crunch` - у некоторых людей возникают  с этим проблемы, если они настраивают компиляцию вручную.

Comment: в смысле "если они настраивают компиляцию вручную"???

Comment: и что нужно предпринять, чтобы исправить ситуацию?

Comment: "Настраивать компиляцию вручную" - это когда пишут свои скрипты для компиляции, с препроцессингом и другими плюшками. И там появление нового каталога с кешированием может мешать. Некоторые просто удаляют этот каталог перед компиляцией.

Сейчас появился gradle, который решает много вопросов, которые раньше решались только сложной альтирерией.

Если Вы не будете изобретать свои велосипеды, то переживать по поводу каталога crunch Вам скорее всего не нужно будет.

Comment: Спасибо за разъяснение. Никаких собственноручно написанных скриптов я в проект не добавлял.
gradle - он ведь только в AndroidStudio. Если как-то его можно  использовать в Eclipse посоветуйте - буду благодарен.